# Elastic Search adding a text field to my aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

I have article information like this in Elastic Search:

```
{
   "ArticleId":355027,
   "ArticleNumber":"433398",
   "CharacteristicsMultiValue":[
      {
         "Name":"Aantal cartridges",
         "Value":"4",
         "NumValue":4,
         "Priority":2147483647
      },
      {
         "Name":"ADF",
         "Value":"Ja",
         "Priority":10,
         "Description":"Een Automatic Document Feeder (ADF), of automatische documentinvoer, laat een multifunctionele printer (all-in-one) automatisch meerdere vellen na elkaar verwerken. Door meerdere vellen in de ADF te plaatsen, wordt ieder vel papier stuk voor stuk automatisch gekopieerd of gescand."
      },
      {
         "Name":"Scanresolutie",
         "Value":"600x600 DPI",
         "Priority":2147483647
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm running the following query to retrieve all the occurrences of the `CharacteristicsMultiValue` for my search with all possible values and sort them to my liking.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
     "query": "433398",
     "default_operator": "and"
    }
  },
  "aggs":{
    "CharacteristicsMultiValue":{
      "nested":{
        "path":"CharacteristicsMultiValue"
       },
       "aggs":{
         "Name":{
           "terms":{
            "field":"CharacteristicsMultiValue.Name",
            "size":25
          },
          "aggs":{
            "Value":{
              "terms":{
                "field":"CharacteristicsMultiValue.Value",
                "size":25
              }
            }, 
            "Priority":{
              "avg":{
                "field":"CharacteristicsMultiValue.Priority"
              }
            },
            "Characteristics_sort": {
              "bucket_sort": {
                "sort": [
                  { "Priority": { "order": "asc" } } 
                ]                               
              }
            }       
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result shows  a list of `CharacteristicsMultiValue` like below.

```
{
   "key":"ADF",
   "doc_count":1,
   "Priority":{
      "value":10
   },
   "Value":{
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound":0,
      "sum_other_doc_count":0,
      "buckets":[
         {
            "key":"Ja",
            "doc_count":1
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

This all works great. I want to make a change so the the `CharacteristicsMultiValue.Description` field is included in the aggregation. I'm not really experienced with Elastic Search, but I feel I should be able to do this pretty easily.

I did some research and to my understanding I would need to add a new sub aggregation for the description column. I tried to do that by adding the JSON below to my current query on several places but I keep getting `404` errors. Could anyone tell me how I could add (the first found) description field to my aggregation.

```
"aggs":{
    "Description":{
        "terms":{
            "field":"CharacteristicsMultiValue.Description",
            "size":1
        }
    }
}
```

---

I tested the solution proposed by Joe. This results in the following error response:

```
{ 
  "error": { 
    "root_cause": [ 
      {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [CharacteristicsMultiValue.Description] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "articles_dev1_nl",
        "node": "HiGH6JY9QvOozRSWJmFXpw",
        "reason": {
          "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
          "reason": "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [CharacteristicsMultiValue.Description] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."
        }
      }
    ],
    "caused_by": {
      "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
      "reason": "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [CharacteristicsMultiValue.Description] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory.",
      "caused_by": {
        "type": "illegal_argument_exception",
        "reason": "Text fields are not optimised for operations that require per-document field data like aggregations and sorting, so these operations are disabled by default. Please use a keyword field instead. Alternatively, set fielddata=true on [CharacteristicsMultiValue.Description] in order to load field data by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can use significant memory."
      }
    }
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you're getting `404` errors -- it's usually `400 Bad Request` if your aggregations' syntax is off.

Either way, if you want to find the top `Description` terms under every bucketed `Value`, you can use:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "433398",
      "default_operator": "and"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "CharacteristicsMultiValue": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "CharacteristicsMultiValue"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "Name": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "CharacteristicsMultiValue.Name",
            "size": 25
          },
          "aggs": {
            "Value": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "CharacteristicsMultiValue.Value",
                "size": 25
              },
    -->       "aggs": {
                "Description": {
                  "terms": {
                    "field": "CharacteristicsMultiValue.Description",
                    "size": 1
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "Priority": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "CharacteristicsMultiValue.Priority"
              }
            },
            "Characteristics_sort": {
              "bucket_sort": {
                "sort": [
                  {
                    "Priority": {
                      "order": "asc"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Generally speaking, [sub-aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#run-sub-aggs) adhere to the following schema:

```json
{
  "query": { },  // optional query
  "aggs": {
    "your_agg_name": {
      "agg_type": {
        // agg spec
      },
      "aggs": {
        "your_sub_agg_name_1": {
          "agg_type": {
            // agg spec
          }
        },
        "your_sub_agg_name_2_if_needed": {
          "agg_type": {
            // agg spec
          }
        },
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and you can:

- **nest further sub-aggs** like you're already doing with `Name->Value` or `Value->Description` from my example
- or keep them on the **same level** like you did with `Name->Value` and `Name->Priority`.

---

Tip: your query is already quite heavily nested so you could explore the `typed_keys` [query parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#return-agg-type) to determine more easily which bucket corresponds to which sub-aggregation.

---

#### Edit

As described in the error msg, the `Description` field needs to be aggregatable *before* any aggregations are performed.

So if you drop your index, you should turn `fielddata` on:

```json
PUT articles_dev1_nl
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "CharacteristicsMultiValue": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          .... other props ...
          
          "Description": {
            "type": "text",
            "fielddata": true        <---
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

or, if your index already exists, you can use the [update API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#put-mapping-api-example):

```json
PUT articles_dev1_nl/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "CharacteristicsMultiValue": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "Description": {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can learn more about `fielddata` vs. `keyword` [here in the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#fielddata-mapping-param).

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I indeed get a `400` error but it's displayed as a `404` in my test tool for some reason. The way you proposed it is how I thought it should be done too. However I still get the `400` error.

Comment: Can you paste the full error inside the question?

Comment: I added the error reponse to the question.

Comment: I updated my answer -- I thought your `Description` was already aggregatable. Hope it makes more sense now.

Comment: Setting `fieldata` to `true` resulted in an error creating the index. I noticed that other fields where defined as `keyword` fields so i changed the description field to that type as well. This solved the issue. Thank you for your great explanation.

Comment: Gotcha. You're welcome!